# REST API sending JWT

Tags: android, ios, rest, cookies, jwt

I'm developing a small REST API that will be used by browsers and Android / iOS / Windows Phone applications. I'm using JWT for authentication. Since in the API every url must receive the token, I'm stuck thinking about how to send the token to the API so that it's compatible also with mobile apps.

I can only think of two options:
First: Cookies, but I do not know if android / iOS / Windows Phone applications can use cookies just like browsers do. Can they?

Second: Using POST to send the token on every request. I know it would work, but I find it unprofessional and I'm sure there is some other way to make it easier.

Would cookies work? Does anyone have any idea how to do it right?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android and iOs applications do not use cookies. You need to store the JWT in local storage and include it in each POST request. The recommended way is using the `Authorization` header, but it is not mandatory

To store the token locally you can use perfectly cookies for the web application and Preferences for Android and iOS

Comment: I'll look for information about `Authorization` header. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

jwt it your best choice 
the main idea is to generate token using your credential that have 3 part the first and second part contains user info and the third part is generated by the first 2 part and the server key

you can see this example building by laravel and angularjs with full description 
[example here](https://www.toptal.com/web/cookie-free-authentication-with-json-web-tokens-an-example-in-laravel-and-angularjs)

update:
the best is to send it in request header Authorization : Bearer cn389ncoiwuencr[jwt token] it will work in both web and mobil

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself. I have no problems with JWT, I know how they work and how to manage them. I'm looking for the best way to send the token in both browsers and phone apps so that the same backend script is able to read it without having to change anything depending on where the request comes from.

Comment: the best is to send it in request header Authorization : Bearer cn389ncoiwuencr[jwt token]

it will work in both web and mobile